# DjangoRestFramework Serializer возвращает пустой объект

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Когда я пытаюсь сериализовать объект возвращается пустой json.

---

models.py

---

```
class EducationProgram(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Автор')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Название')
    specification = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Описание')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'образовательная программа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'образовательные программы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Lesson(models.Model):
    ed_program = models.ManyToManyField('EducationProgram', verbose_name='образовательная программа',
                                        related_name='lesson')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='Тема урока')
    specification = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    video = models.URLField(unique=True, verbose_name='Видео')
    length = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Длительность')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'урок'
        verbose_name_plural = 'уроки'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

serializeers.py

---

```
class LessonerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Lesson
        fields = ['ed_program']


class EducationProgramerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lesson_list = LessonerSerializer(
        read_only=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.EducationProgram
        fields = ['lesson_list']
```

---

views.py

---

```
class EducationProgramList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.EducationProgramerializer
    queryset = models.EducationProgram.objects.all()
```

Comment: А можете показать как выглядит ваш view? Есть предположение что ошибка там.

Comment: @E1mir, вот view 
class EducationProgramList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.EducationProgramerializer
    queryset = models.EducationProgram.objects.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lesson_list = LessonerSerializer(
    read_only = True,
    many = True,
    source = 'lessons',
)
```

Разве не так? Нужно указать, что сериализуется массив, и поле, если имя не совпадает с ним.

Comment: не получается так. Вывод также пустой.

Comment: спасибо, всё-таки получилось. Сначала ответ скопировал полностью с source = 'lessons', а там нужно source = 'lesson'. Все получилось, спасибо!